# javascript function parameter place

Tags: javascript, function

How to write function(object) with 2 methods (alert and console.log) to be able to use it like this:

```
fname("text").alert //-now text is alerted;
fname("text").cons //-now text shows in console log.
```

the methods are not important byt the way of execution. I know that it must be self invoiking function but i cant do it. I dont want to use it this way -  fname.alert("text").

Greetings
Kriss

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible in any sane way that works everywhere. The example you posted would require you to define an accessor for those properties - and that only works with modern JS engines.

Anyway, here's code that would actually do this. **But please do not use this in any real application! See the last code block for a better solution**

```
function fname(message) {
    var obj = {};
    Object.defineProperty(obj, 'alert', {
        get: function() {
            alert(message);
        }
    });
    Object.defineProperty(obj, 'cons', {
        get: function() {
            console.log(message);
        }
    });
    return obj;
}
```

This works because `fname('hello').alert` will cause the getter function for the `alert` property to be executed - and while such a function should usually return a value there's nothing to stop it from doing something like showing an `alert()` message.

---

What you *could* achieve in a way that works everywhere would be something like that though:

```
fname('text').alert();
fname('text').cons();
```

This could be done like this:

```
function fname(message) {
    return {
        alert: function() {
            alert(message);
        },
        cons: function() {
            console.log(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Than you very much Greetings

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept the answer though as this is pretty much the way to stay thanks here on Stack Overflow. You can do so by clicking the gray checkmark icon on the left side of my post.

Answer (score 4):

```
function fname(str) {
   return {
      alert:function(){alert(str)},
      cons:function(){console.log(str)}
   }
}
```

Doing `fname("text").alert()` alerts `text`.

Comment: This might not be the most efficient way of doing things, as I've read that anonymous functions are actually reconstructed in the function they belong to.

Comment: Efficiency would be relevant if we could see a use for such a construct.